# Libcurl - client SSL authentication with native windows crypto - is it possible?

Tags: windows, authentication, curl, ssl, libcurl

I'm using libcurl on Windows, I need to implement client-side SSL authentication. The catch is, client certificate, used for authentication, is marked as non-exportable. It means, that I cannot export it and feed to, say, OpenSSL - I need to make libcurl use native Windows crypto (WinSSL / SecureChannel / whatever it's called).

Is it possible? If yes, what do I pass as CURLOPT_SSLCERT & CURLOPT_SSLKEY - somehow, I understand, I need to reference the keys - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested - not currently possible: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2013-07/0010.html .

Comment: this is dated 2013, and I'm looking to find out if any progress has been made on it. I found this from 2016: https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2016-06/0032.html which implies no, and this: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/todo.html#Add_support_for_client_certifica which also does. This guy: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1897#issuecomment-337268138 makes an interesting comment, but I don't see how to make it work without hacking libcurl. Anybody know?